# How to generate javadoc documentation with umlauts?

Tags: html, encoding, javadoc, diacritics

I am trying to generate Java documentation in Eclipse. The source files are UTF-8 encoded and contain some [umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)). The resulting HTML files do not specify an encoding and do not use HTML entities, so the umlauts aren't displayed correctly in any browser.

What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See the [-charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#charset), [-encoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#encoding) and [-docencoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#docencoding) flags for the [javadoc command](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#options).

- `-encoding` specifies the input encoding
- `-docencoding` specifies the output encoding
- `-charset` makes javadoc include a meta tag with encoding info

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought there must be some easy way to do this in eclipse, since eclipse already knows the encoding of the input files.

Comment: It is really annoying that there are both `-charset` and `-docencoding` options - I can not imagine a case where these two would be set different (or one would be set and the other one not).

Answer (score 57):

Modified from [Eclipse javadoc in utf-8](http://checked-trick.blogspot.com/2010/10/eclipse-javadoc-in-utf-8.html):

Project -> Generate Javadoc -> Next -> on the last page, in *Extra Javadoc options* write:

```
-encoding UTF-8 -charset UTF-8 -docencoding UTF-8
```

Comment: I don't see an *export* option in my Eclipse. Where would one find this?

Comment: In Eclipse 3.6.2, this would be in the Project menu. Which Eclipse version are you using? Also, better put these arguments to *Javadoc options* instead of *VM options*.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate your javadoc with an ant task and you use UTF-8 you can do:

```
<javadoc encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" docencoding="UTF-8" sourcepath="yoursources" destdir="yourdocdir" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When generating the javadoc with Gradle add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
javadoc {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.docEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.charSet = 'UTF-8'
}
```